# How to get address in C# function from delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, c#-4.0

I have some DLL file. It contain some some method with name is "ABSDefaultCallback". So I assign this method like this.

```
IntPtr hMod = LoadLibrary("bsgui.dll");
IntPtr pAddr = GetProcAddress(hMod, "ABSDefaultCallback");
op.Callback = pAddr;
```

it is work on perfectly. But I want to call my own method which name is "Callback" except "ABSDefaultCallback". I'm try to do this one like this.

```
DELEGATE_TestFunc fred = new DELEGATE_TestFunc(Callback);
void* pfred = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(fred).ToPointer();
op.Callback = (IntPtr)pfred;
```

But this one not work on perfectly. How to fix my problem?

Comment: Probably calling conventions. You will have to emit a custom delegate at runtime or create on in IL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the correct signatures for everything you're doing via p/Invoke.  If you don't, then you need to fix that first.

According to [this article](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/delegates-as-callbacks-part-2/), you might be experiencing a problem with your delegate being garbage collected.

They use `GCHandle.Alloc` on the delegate to create a reference that won't be garbage collected.

```
static void DemonstrateCallBack_With_GCHandle()
{
    var callback_delegate = new CallBack(CallBackFunction);

    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(callback_delegate);
    IntPtr intptr_delegate =
        Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback_delegate);

    PerformActionWithCallBack(intptr_delegate);

    gch.Free();
}
```

If this ends up working for you, I'd suggest you wrap the `GCHandle.Alloc` and `gch.Free` in an object that implements `IDisposable`, and possibly look into using `SafeHandle`.

This article might provide some of the relevant details: http://obiwanjacobi.blogspot.com/2007/05/robust-pinvoke-for-windows-midi-api.html

Comment: Should you not be passing the `GCHandle` to `PerformActionWithCallBack` ?

Comment: @leppie: This code is from the article, and I'm just passing on the info.  What you said seems to make perfect sense to me, but it isn't what the article did.  I don't actually know the mechanics of how this works, and I'm just trying to google the problem into submission :)

Comment: Neither do I  :)  I normally dont bother pinning pointers, although I should.